# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') when Clicking button on calculator

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Im building a calculator and I don't know where's the problem:

```
  appendNumber(number){
      if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.') && this.currentOperand == undefined) return
      this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
    }
```

This throws TypeError, when I change this.currentOperand.toString() with: `this.currentOperand` - when I click for example button it shows undefined6
Where is the problem?

```
numberButtons.forEach(button => {
     button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText) // it Throws error here too 
                                              //HTMLButtonElement<anonymous>
      calculator.updateDisplay()
     })
   })
```

When I ctrl C + v the source code from where I'm learning the error disappears... And it's 1:1 anyway,

EDIT: My mistake, code should look like this:

```
        appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
          }
```

And there's no logic in my calc yet I just want to make buttons after click visible on calc bar, not undefined..

Here's the result when I delete `.toString()` before currentOperand
https://imgur.com/a/dALGFYv

Answer (score 0):

This condition is contradictory:

```
if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.') && this.currentOperand == undefined) return
```

You are checking if currentOperand includes a dot and is undefined at the same time. That's not possible.

I assume you wanted to use the logical OR operator `||`.

```
if (number === '.' && (this.currentOperand == undefined || this.currentOperand.includes('.'))) return
```

Or maybe you are doing some optional chaining, and actually want this:

```
if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand?.includes('.')) return
```

That would evaluate to true only if currentOperand is defined and includes a dot.

We can't know for sure what you need since we haven't seen your calculator logic.